# Getting Lua package.cpath & path with C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, lua, qt5, lua-table

The C++ (using Qt libs) project I am coding for has am "embedded" Lua 5.1 subsystem which is represented by, as I understand it, a `lua_State`; in order to set up where external Lua modules (`.lua` files) and libraries (`.dll` or `.so` files depending on OS) are stored so that they can be `required` as needed, I need to manipulate the global `package.path` and `package.cpath` table members.

I have code that can successfully **set** those entries with C++ code and I can see the results in the embedded system.

However I cannot seem to be able to **get** them from the C++ side of things.  Currently, for `package.path` I have the following:

```
QString TLuaInterpreter::getLuaPath()
{
    lua_State* L = pGlobalLua;
    if (!L) {
        qDebug() << "LUA CRITICAL ERROR: in TLuaInterpreter::getLuaPath - no suitable Lua execution unit found.";
        return QString("LUA CRITICAL ERROR");
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "package.path");
    lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "package.path");
    QString result(QString::fromUtf8(lua_tostring(L, 1)));

    return result;
}
```

I would expect a `;` separated list of entries like:

```
./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua
```

but I only ever get an empty `QString` back instead.  Now I am not as familiar with Lua as I am with C/C++ so it is possible that this is a lua stack manipulation issue, but I am certain that I have the right `lua_State` instance - so what is wrong in this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `lua_getglobal(L, "package.path")` at once, you have to get `package` on the stack first and then `path`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "cpath" is a field of "package" table. You should use something like this:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "package");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "cpath");
```